# How to set up Vertica Connection in DBeaver?

Tags: vertica, dbeaver

I was trying to setup Vertica Connection in DBeaver. But getting following error :
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txUGu.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have the Vertica JDBC driver?

Try to find a file named `vertica-jdbc-10.1.1-0.jar` (or similar, mind the version), on your hard drive.

If you don't have it, then go here to download it:

https://www.vertica.com/client_drivers/11.0.x/11.0.0-0/vertica-jdbc-11.0.0-0.jar

Then, you will have to store it in a safe directory, and tell DBeaver where to find it.

For how to tell DBeaver that, check DBeaver's documentation